# How to calculate the expected cost?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not good at probability. And while I was solving a computation problem I found this difficulty:
**Problem definition:**

> The Little Elephant from the Zoo of Lviv is going to the Birthday
>   Party of the Big Hippo tomorrow. Now he wants to prepare a gift for
>   the Big Hippo. He has N balloons, numbered from 1 to N. The i-th
>   balloon has the color Ci and it costs Pi dollars. The gift for the Big
>   Hippo will be any subset (chosen randomly, possibly empty) of the
>   balloons such that the number of different colors in that subset is at
>   least M. Help Little Elephant to find the expected cost of the gift.

**Input**

> The first line of the input contains a single integer T - the number
>   of test cases. T test cases follow. The first line of each test case
>   contains a pair of integers N and M. The next N lines contain N pairs
>   of integers Ci and Pi, one pair per line.

**Output**

> In T lines print T real numbers - the answers for the corresponding
>   test cases. Your answer will considered correct if it has at most
>   10^-6 absolute or relative error.

Example

Input:

> 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 1 4
>
> 2 7
>
> 2 1
>
> 1 4
>
> 2 7

**Output:**

> 11.000000000
>
> 7.333333333

So, Here I don't understand why the expected cost of the gift for the second case is 7.333333333, because the expected cost equals `Summation[xP(x)]` and according to this formula it should be 33/2?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second test case, you have three possible combinations that have at least 1 different colour: $\{1\}$ with cost $4$, $\{2\}$ with cost $7$, and $\{1,2\}$ with cost $4+7=11$. Your formula gives you
$$E[X] = 4 \frac{1}{3} + 7 \frac{1}{3} + 11 \frac{1}{3} = \frac{22}{3} \approx 7.333333333.$$